# Cannot access to ResetMyPassword in Apache Superset 3.7

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I'm running Apache Superset using `docker-compose up -d`. I can login using admin/admin user and password but I can't change it. ResetMyPassword button is not viewed in profile view. I tried creating another user, but I get the same problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the folder in which you ran docker-compose, and run the following command:

```
docker-compose exec superset bash -c 'export FLASK_APP=superset && flask fab create-admin'
```

(you might need sudo as well)

After you create a new admin user (with different credentials!), you can go into the old admin user's profile, set it as inactive, and login using the new credentials.